# How to make zsh pass the manual section to the man command when the `separate-sections` style is set?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

When asking for a completion by pressing Tab on the zsh command line, the matches can be grouped according to their tag provided that the `group-name` style is set to an empty string:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format '%d'
```

In the case of the `$ man` command, the matches can be divided further if the `separate-sections` style is set to `true` for the `manuals` tag:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format '%d'
zstyle ':completion:*:manuals' separate-sections true
```

As a result, if I press Tab after `$ man write`, the completion system suggests these matches:

```
$ man write
manual page, section 1 (general commands)
write
manual page, section 2 (system calls)
write   writev
```

And if I select the `write` match in the first list, `$ man` opens the `write` page in the first section of the manual.

But if I select the `write` match in the second list, `$ man` still opens the `write` page in the first section, while the description of the list mentions the second section of the manual.

Is it possible to make zsh pass the relevant manual section to the man command when the `separate-sections` style is set?

I'm using `zsh 5.6.2-dev-0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add simply the following:

```bsh
zstyle ':completion:*' insert-sections true
```

This is unfortunately not documented, but you can see it here from the code: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/8becb893579af0ca41617a15d3afcbea588fe621/Completion/Unix/Command/_man#L448

I tested it and it works.